# viewpager lagging when listview got too many items

Tags: android, performance, listview, android-viewpager, universal-image-loader

I'm using a viewpager ([SmartTabLayout](https://github.com/ogaclejapan/SmartTabLayout)) with four tabs (fragments). In all four fragments i am using custom listviews. These listviews load images from sd card per item. I use [Nostra's universal image loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) for that.

Everything works fine that far. But when I increase the number of items in one of the aforementioned listviews from ten to around fifty items, the viewpager doesn't swipe smoothly anymore.

I use memory and disc caching for pictures. Here are my configs of image loader:

```
File cacheDir = StorageUtils.getOwnCacheDirectory(context, 
            Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + File.separator + Constants.DIRECTORY_TEAM_CHANNEL);//for caching

    ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context);
    config.diskCacheFileNameGenerator(new HashCodeFileNameGenerator());
    config.diskCacheSize(50 * 1024 * 1024); // 50 MiB
    config.diskCache(new UnlimitedDiskCache(cacheDir)); // You can pass your own disc cache implementation
    config.memoryCacheSize(41943040);
    config.threadPoolSize(10);
    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config.build());
```

And I use following option parameters:

```
mImgDisplayOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.default_user)
            .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.default_user)
            .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.default_user)
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisc(true)
            .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_POWER_OF_2)
            .build();
```

Here's the complete listview adapter:

```
public class CustomContactListAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
private static final int TYP_REGISTERED = 0;
private static final int TYP_UNREGISTERED = 1;
private static final int VIEW_TYPE_COUNT = 2;

private Activity activity;
private List<User> userItems;
private DisplayImageOptions mOptions;

private DBHandler dbHandler;
private DisplayImageOptions mImgDisplayOptions;

static ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

public CustomContactListAdapter(Activity activity, List<User> userItems)
{
    this.activity = activity;
    this.userItems = userItems;
    dbHandler = DBHandler.getInstance(activity.getApplicationContext());


    mImgDisplayOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.default_user)
            .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.default_user)
            .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.default_user)
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisc(true)
            .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_POWER_OF_2)
            .build();
}

@Override
public int getCount()
{
    return userItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position)
{
    return userItems.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position)
{
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) 
{
    return (userItems.get(position).getToken() != null) ? TYP_REGISTERED : TYP_UNREGISTERED;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount()
{
    return VIEW_TYPE_COUNT;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    ViewHolder viewholder=null;
    int type = getItemViewType(position);    

    if (convertView == null)
    {    
        viewholder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


        switch(type)
        {
            case TYP_REGISTERED:

                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_list_row, parent, false);
                viewholder.thumbNail = (ImageView ) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail_reg);
                viewholder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name_reg);
                viewholder.lastComment = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lastComment_reg);
                viewholder.regState = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.regState_reg);

                viewholder.thumbNail.setMaxHeight(60);
                viewholder.thumbNail.setMaxWidth(60);
                break;

            case TYP_UNREGISTERED:

                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_list_not_registered_row, parent, false);
                viewholder.thumbNail = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail_not_reg);
                viewholder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name_not_reg);
                viewholder.phonenumber = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.phonenumber_not_reg);
                viewholder.regState = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.regState_not_reg);

                viewholder.thumbNail.setMaxHeight(60);
                viewholder.thumbNail.setMaxWidth(60);
                break;
        }

        convertView.setTag(viewholder);            
    }
    else
    {
        viewholder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    // getting user data for the row
    User user = userItems.get(position);
    String userName = "";

    switch(type)
    {
        case TYP_REGISTERED:
        {
            //thumbnail
            if (user.getThumbnail() != null)
            {
                if(user.getThumbnail() != null)
                {
                    imageLoader.displayImage(Constants.ABS_PATH_USER_THUMBNAIL + user.getThumbnail() + ".jpg", viewholder.thumbNail, mImgDisplayOptions);
                }
                else
                {
                    viewholder.thumbNail.setImageResource(R.drawable.default_user);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                viewholder.thumbNail.setImageResource(R.drawable.default_user);
            }

            //firstname
            if (user.getFirstname() != null) {
                userName += user.getFirstname() + " ";
            }

            //lastname
            if (user.getLastname() != null) {
                userName += user.getLastname();
            }
            viewholder.name.setText(userName);


            Chat chat = dbHandler.getChatByUser(user);
            if (chat != null) {
                Comment lastComment = dbHandler.getLastCommentFromUser(chat, user);

                if (lastComment != null) {
                    viewholder.lastComment.setText((lastComment.getContent().length() > 25)
                            ? lastComment.getContent().substring(0, 25) + "..." : lastComment.getContent());
                } else {
                    viewholder.lastComment.setText("");
                }

            } else {
                viewholder.lastComment.setText("");
            }


            // registration state (registered)
            viewholder.regState.setText(String.valueOf("mobil"));

            break;
        }
        case TYP_UNREGISTERED:
        {
            if (user.getThumbnail() != null)
            {

                if(user.getThumbnail() != null)
                {
                    imageLoader.displayImage(Constants.ABS_PATH_USER_THUMBNAIL + user.getThumbnail() + ".jpg", viewholder.thumbNail, mImgDisplayOptions);
                }
                else
                {
                    viewholder.thumbNail.setImageResource(R.drawable.default_user);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                viewholder.thumbNail.setImageResource(R.drawable.default_user);
            }

            if (user.getFirstname() != null) {
                userName += user.getFirstname() + " ";
            }

            if (user.getLastname() != null) {
                userName += user.getLastname();
            }

            viewholder.name.setText(userName);


            // phonenumber
            viewholder.phonenumber.setText(user.getPhonenumber());

            // registration state (unregistered, send invitation)
            viewholder.regState.setText(String.valueOf("Einladen"));

            break;
        }
    }

    return convertView;
}

private static class ViewHolder
{
    ImageView thumbNail;
    TextView name;
    TextView phonenumber;
    TextView lastComment;
    TextView regState; 
}
}
```

Comment: Can you post your ListViewAdpater code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ListViews don't recycle their views when they scroll off the screen. Having lots of fragments, each rendering images in a ListView, can be quite costly.

Have a look into the [RecyclerView](http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html) if you want to avoid lag. They're quite well documented, easy to implement and HEAPS more efficient.

**Update:**
I noticed that you that you're loading images while you're scroll (which I didn't think would be a problem since it should be loading asynchronously).

According to the documentation, you can pause loading while you scroll ListViews via the `PauseOnScrollListener`.
To avoid list (grid, ...) scrolling lags you can use PauseOnScrollListener:

```
boolean pauseOnScroll = false; // or true
boolean pauseOnFling = true; // or false
PauseOnScrollListener listener = new PauseOnScrollListener(imageLoader, pauseOnScroll, pauseOnFling);
listView.setOnScrollListener(listener);
```

Took that straight out of the [Useful Info UIL Documentation](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/wiki/Useful-Info).
Hopefully that solves the problem :)

**Update**
For those who want to use PauseOnScrollListener on a RecyclerView, here's nostra13's implementation: https://gist.github.com/nostra13/806d01ebd604f3adf241

Comment: I tried the RecyclerView and the performance has obviously improved, BUT now when scrolling down and up the listview (receyclerView) laggs a bit. What image loader can you recommend or are the configs inefficiently set?

Comment: When I need to do image loading (especially via HTTP) I usually use an [LruCache<String, Bitmap>](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html), there's actually a heap of information on using Bitmaps efficiently on the official Android Documentation. You might need to down-sample your images too (I had a similar problem when using the NavigationView).

Comment: But is there a way to achieve this effect with UIL? Can you please give a little code sample how to load a pic in an ImageView with above mentioned caching method?

Comment: Your code looks good to me (except you have a redundant `if (user.getThumbnail() != null)` nested inside itself). I think it has to do with the fact that you're loading images while you fling the ListView really fast. See my updated answer.

Comment: now that I have used RecyclerViews (as my listview) I'm not able to add a PauseOnScrollListener anymore. Is there a way to cast it or anything else to get it work with RecyclerView?

Comment: nostra13 actually wrote one for RecyclerViews: https://gist.github.com/nostra13/806d01ebd604f3adf241 (not sure if it's the most up to date yet)

Comment: I even found his wrapper class. With this I can add scrollListener without type problems: [solution here](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/issues/799)

Comment: And yes, now laggs and flings during srolling RecyclerView are almost away. Never thought listviews can be so laggy.

Comment: Yup, the `ListView` can get incredibly slow for long and/or complicated lists. If you're still having trouble with images I highly recommend you read [Displaying Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html), that said UIL covers most of these topics anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with viewpagers is that they inflate views ahead of the current one. This can cause issues if you are inflating tons of resources such as what you are doing now. I would recommend inflating just the listview rather than all the information. The you use the onPageSelected method in your activity to call a method to start loading the information. That way only the active fragment loads. If you still are not sure what I mean let me know!

Comment: Actually it sounds like issue is his ListViews are loading images before they need them.